# Why doesn't this JavaScript function `submitForm()` work?

Tags: javascript

I am using the below snippet.

```
  <script>
  function submitForm()
  {
      var urlParam = "init_gender="+document.getElementById("gender").value+"&init_room=1&init_user="+document.getElementById("nickname").value;
      var URL = "client/htmlchat/start.html";
      var encordedUrl = URL+"?"+encodeURI( urlParam );

      document.location.href = encordedUrl;
  }
  </script>
```

With a single `document.getElementById` it works, but now I need to add more information to `urlParam` it has stopped working.

Is it not possible to use more than 1 `document.getElementById` like this, or am I just joining it incorrectly?

Comment: Why are you using JavaScript for this instead of a regular form submission?

Comment: @Quentin Indeed, I think `<form method="get"` would do the same as this JS, correct?

Comment: getElementById("gender").value"&init_room...   There should be a '+' between 'value' and '"&init_room'.   Why not post your code on jsbin.com then paste your link here?

Comment: @Quentin I need input spaces to be shown in the URL as %20, and not + or %2520.

Answer (score 3):

```
lue"&init_
```

You missed the `+` operator

---

As an aside, you should use `encodeURIComponent` on each component of the query string and not `encodeURI` over the whole thing.

Comment: I updated the question, I added the `&` but it still does not work. It works if I revert back to using a single element for example `var urlParam = "init_gender="+document.getElementById("gender").value;`.